# System.InvalidCastException when textboxes are empty

Tags: vb.net

When I type in the first text box, leaving the other text boxes empty, I get this error:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidCastException' occurred in Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll"

```
Public Class myProject_P2

Public Sub CostPerKWH_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles CostPerKWH.TextChanged
    Dim CostPerkwh_Value As Integer = CostPerKWH.Text
    Dim Appliancekwh_Value As Integer = ApplianceKWH.Text
    Dim HourPerDay_Value As Integer = HoursPerDay.Text
    Dim EnergyConsumption_Value As Integer = EnergyConsumptio.Text

    EnergyConsumption_Value = CostPerkwh_Value * Appliancekwh_Value * HourPerDay_Value
End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: The error occurs when you type on the first text box leaving the other text box empty, correct?

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. Yes, that's when I received the error.

Comment: Add `Option Strict On` to the top of your code file.  This will help you immensely.  This line and the others like it are wrong:  `Dim Appliancekwh_Value As Integer = ApplianceKWH.Text`.  You are attempting to assign a String to an Integer variable.  If  you ever enter anything that is not an integer into the text box, your program will crash.

Comment: @ChrisDunaway Thanks for the tips! I added "Option Strict On" That helps a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't really know the flow of your program but if your problem is only that error stated in your question which is `System.InvalidCastException` then try the code I pasted below.

**Before anything else,** *the reason why it throws that error is perhaps you typed on the first field leaving others empty which your first field was programmed that upon text change, the values of other fields will be passed on or assigned to an integer variable. Since they are empty, therefore, the value passed on were `""` values or `empty string` values. String values assigned to an integer will surely cause an error.* Try to validate before passing the values and I suggest not to put the *assigning of values* in your text change, rather, try adding a `button` and add there the codes. Upon button click, the process goes on like this:

```
Dim CostPerkwh_Value As Integer
Dim Appliancekwh_Value As Integer
Dim HourPerDay_Value As Integer
Dim EnergyConsumption_Value As Integer

Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    If IsNumeric(CostPerKWH.Text) And IsNumeric(ApplianceKWH.Text) _
        And IsNumeric(HoursPerDay.Text) And IsNumeric(EnergyConsumptio.Text) Then
        CostPerkwh_Value = CostPerKWH.Text
        Appliancekwh_Value = ApplianceKWH.Text
        HourPerDay_Value = HoursPerDay.Text
        EnergyConsumption_Value = EnergyConsumptio.Text

        EnergyConsumption_Value = CostPerkwh_Value * Appliancekwh_Value * HourPerDay_Value
        MsgBox(EnergyConsumption_Value)
    Else
        MsgBox("Some inputs are not in numeric.")
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: MAC thanks for your help. Your code got rid of the error. Now I'm having a little trouble getting the msgBox to display the calculated value. If I enter integers in the input fields and click Button1 I get the _Else_ message. Any ideas what might be going wrong.

Comment: do you by chance have only 3 text boxes? cause in this sample, i used 4

Comment: do you have EnergyConsumtio textbox or no?

Comment: Ah ha! yes I see what was happening. I was trying to have label display the calculated value changed it to a textBox and now its working. Thank you so much from helping.

Answer (score 0):

another solution would be:

```
if TryCast(Textboxt1.text, integer) then
   ' do something
end if
```

[MSDN TryCast Documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zyy863x8.aspx)